# Cannot get data from response on console log using nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is the response part i have did.

```
app.get('/api/followers', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
var instagramId = req.user.instagramId
console.log("instagramId",req.user.fullName);
var followersUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by';
var params = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };
request.get({ url: followersUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
console.log("Response",response.body.data);
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  res.send(body.data);
}
else{
res.send(error);
}
  });
});
```

when printing  console.log("Response",response.body.data); 
i get the following response:

```
Response [{username:'aaa',
prof pic:'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg',
id:'56877787',full_name:'AARON'}]
```

But i need to get the value inside the array.
i need the value for username.
how to retrieve the value??

Comment: does anyone know how to do this??

Comment: Try `console.log("Response",response.body.data[0].username)` !